# Discrepancy between deterministic and stochastic control problems...

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, control-theory, stochastic-analysis, optimal-control

Suppose that one wants to control a diffusion process
$$
dX_t^u = \mu(X_t^u,u)dt + \sigma dW_t; \qquad X_0^u=x
$$
in order to optimize a stochastic control problem with value function
$$
V_T(u)=\mathbb{E}[f(X^u_T) + \int_0^T g(X_t^u)dt].
$$
Where $f,g$ are bounded smooth functions and $u$ is an admissible control.

Now suppose that one wants to optimize the deterministic control problem:
$$
\partial_t x_t^u = \mu(x_t^u,u)dt ; \qquad X_0^u=x
$$
with value function
$$
v_T(u)=f(X^u_T) + \int_0^T g(X_t^u)dt;
$$
where in this case $u$ is optimized over all determinsitic controls.

For small $\sigma$, when can one guarantee that the optimal policies of both problems are "close" (in expectation or some other appropriate sense)?

Comment: You have some rotational issue in that $\epsilon$ doesn't appear in the problem. Did you mean $\sigma$?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that.

Comment: A lot will hinge on what controls you can use, particularly since you have no explicit penalty for large or rapidly oscillatory controls. With enough flexibility in controls you can basically sit on the deterministic optimum even if $\sigma$ is not small.

Comment: It's a compact set of controls

Comment: It also matters what $\mu$ is, since the effect of the control hinges on the behavior of $\mu$. Also compact in what? And can the control itself be stochastic (e.g. by depending on the history thus far)? There's a lot that goes into this.